# How to disable "Your edit was saved" popup?

Tags: mediawiki

When using the MediaWiki software, how do you disable the popup saying "Your edit was saved." from appearing?

Answer (score 2):

This feature has been created after A/B testing to provide users a [feedback that their edit indeed has been saved](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Post-edit_feedback). The module providing this functionality was [unconditionally loaded](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/cbe6abfd239a451a5500b0affe1abbbd73d03d64/includes/page/Article.php#L742), while now it's only loaded [if a cookie](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/be629bf6e8afd47cfda515756f15962c549e9014/includes/page/Article.php#L880L881), was set in [EditPage.php](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/be629bf6e8afd47cfda515756f15962c549e9014/includes/EditPage.php#L1591). It will trigger a label/popup on the next page loading with `action=view` (the default action). There was an [HTML snippet](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/commit/f8ac9bb2e6a28c0623a4aa5289c24de8394d9fae#diff-e1c35ebc7de26e494f836096fd5425d7L1), while now, HTML is generated by [JavaScript `mediawiki.action.view.postEdit.js`](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/master/resources/src/mediawiki.action/mediawiki.action.view.postEdit.js).

### 2 ways to get rid of it:

- As a server administrator (and you'll have to remember to re-install this hack after upgrading): Remove the [line](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/cbe6abfd239a451a5500b0affe1abbbd73d03d64/includes/page/Article.php#L742) loading the module `mediawiki.action.view.postEdit` - this will possibly save you a few bytes bandwidth, too.
- As a site administrator: Hide the message by adding the following to [MediaWiki:Common.css](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Stylesheets):

```css
.postedit {
      display: none;
}
```